# Add horizontally scrollable filter options under UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uisearchcontroller

I am developing a page that allows the user to search contents in a table, and I want to add some filter options under the search bar. I've added the UISearchController programmatically into the navbar, but I want to know how to add a list of horizontally scrollable filter options under the search bar (Just like the layout on the right in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrjIq.png). Thanks!

I realize that this is probably something that has been asked/answered before, but I cannot find a single page discussing this. If you have a link to a solution I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a horizontally scrolling collectionView with filter buttons in them and set it below the UISearchController.

You can create a collection view like this programmatically:

```
 lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor =  UIColor.white
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return cv
    }()
```

Now you can add items to this collectionView using cellForItemAtIndexPath, numberOfItemsInSection and other delegates.

You would need to then set constraints on the collectionView like this:

```
 collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchController.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
```

Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: So, in this case, is the collectionView created programmatically? When I add a collectionView to this code it throws the error 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'

Comment: Updated the answer, hope this helps. If the answer helped, plz don't forget to mark it as the answer. Good luck.

Comment: this works great except for one thing. Search controller does not have the component bottomAnchor (used to set the topAnchor of the collection view). When I changed this code to searchController.searchBar.bottomAnchor, the app throws a SIGABRT error. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: also, the collectionView covers the tableView below. I'm thinking I'll just change its top constraint to equal the bottom of the collectionView. Is that the best method?

Comment: Yes collectiokview bottom should be table view top. Also if you are seeing an error try to post it. If the answer was helpful , consider upvoting it. Thanks.